# Nvidia problems on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS fresh install

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

i've installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my machine but i have a problem.

-i have core i9 13900k
-1 samsung nvme 980 plus (with both windows and ubuntu installed)
-Nvidia rtx 2070 super
-mainboard asus rog strix z690-e

after some minutes into ubuntu, the system log off and kill all of my opened applications, i posted an image with some errors.

sorry is my first time with ubuntu.

anyone knows how can i solve this?

[log registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4zJD.png)

Comment: A couple of things. 1. You have Ubuntu 22.04 in the title but in the question you asked about Ubuntu 22. That is a version of Ubuntu Core. 2. There is no registry in Linux that is a Windows feature. Your title says it is a Nvidia problem but nothing in the question is anything about Nvidia. Please edit the question and add or correct the info. Not in comments please.

Comment: sorry, done, added new title with correct version